# Set minimum and Maximum in hour timepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

the image below example of time picker and the minimum of hours is **00** and maximum is **23** .

[example of minimum hour which is 00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIEg5.png)

Here is my code

```
$('.bootstrap-timepicker').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'HH:mm',
    //use24hours: true
});
```

How do i set the minimum hour is **01** and the maximum hour is **24** ??

Comment: Where in the world does the day start at 1 am?

Comment: its not about am and pm ...i just want to get hours format like 01 02 till 24 only for  sending data to backend purpose

Comment: But why? The clock starts at 0 and not 1

Comment: dont asking why its client request ...any help??

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using exactly? Is it this one http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/?

Comment: @j0ste yes sir ..hope u can help me sir

Comment: Now I see there is no `pickDate` option in the eonasdan datetimepicker... So which is it? Tarruda? http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/